# How can I disable an instantiated prefab with a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I thought that it would be as simple as putting gameObject.setActive(false); in the function, but when the function is called on, nothing happens. The play again button that becomes enabled works, as well as the debug.logs. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
    void EndBattle()

{
    playAgain.SetActive(true);

    if (state == BattleState.WON)
    {
        enemyPrefab.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("won");
    }
    else if(state == BattleState.LOST)
    {
        playerPrefab.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("lost");
    }

}
```

Comment: when you instantiate a prefab you would need to remember its reference....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing just this

`Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

do

suppose your script is called MyScript.cs

```
public static GameObject prefabSpawned;

...

prefabSpawned = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

then, if you want to deactivate it at any point, do

`MyScript.prefabSpawned.SetActive(false);`

The advantage of this method is that you can disable the prefab from any script, not just the script you created it from.

Comment: I don't think that I'd need to make the prefabs static since the win/lose states are already in the script. The problem is that for some reason gameObject.SetActive(false) is not doing anything, and the prefab is still active in the scene

Comment: don't make it static then. leave it like ```prefabSpawned = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);```, then ```prefabSpawned.SetActive(false)```. There's no way this doesn't work

Comment: I noticed you found the solution - mine worked as well, even if you had your variables for checking in another script, therefore it's a correct answer and it is seen as good practice to mark the correct answers like so :)

Comment: I did try yours and it didn't work, the only thing that did was when I referenced the child objects. I'll still mark it correct though because you tried to help, and for that I thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was disabling the prefab itself when i should have been disabling the reference to it.